# Unhiding a UIView when button is clicked

Tags: ios, ipad

I've hidden a `UIView` using

```
_loginview.hidden = YES
```

and when I do

```
-(IBaction)logInButton:(id)sender {  
_logInView.hidden = NO;  
}
```

It still doesn't show when I click the button, can anyone help?

Comment: is _logInView a outlet? If so check whether it is properly linked

Answer (score 0):

I have created a Iboutlet property of UIView and connected it with UIView in storyboard. Also ticked hidden.

Screen shot of hidden view is below(color orange). I also sethidden in programmatically way and still working.

[image: hidden view]

And later on button action I perform setHiden as no and it appeared. Code of IBAction is below:-

```
- (IBAction)loginBtn{

  [hidenView setHidden:NO];
}
```

Comment: whether your IBAction method is called or not?

Answer (score 0):

You need to setHidden NO on your View when you clocked on uiButton..

- (IBaction)logInButton:(id)sender{
  [_logInView setHidden:NO];
  }

Answer (score 0):

It is working my end by creating this,
@property(nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet UIView *viewLogin; // in controller.h

@synthesize viewLogin; // in controller.m

set outlet property for viewlogin in storyboard

and with following IBAction event,

```
-(IBAction)login:(id)sender{
    [viewLogin setHidden:NO]; }
```

Answer (score 0):

In storyboard, from connections inspector check that your button is connected properly with a sent event.
Then (if you are performing an async process, maybe login user) try this:

```
[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
    _logInView.hidden = NO;  
}];
```

witch updates the UI from the main thread.
Just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

Better use setAlpha instead of setHidden.